# Cannot open a local json file into new tab in React due to http://localhost:3000/[object%20object]

Tags: json, reactjs, local-files

I am trying to open some random local json file into new tab in React. After getting relative path I'm generating a link using following code.

```
<a type="application/json" target='_blank' href={require('../../storage' + metadata.url)}>
   <strong>{metadata.Name}</strong>
</a>
```

But, when rendering this element in browser I can see wrong *href=[object%20object]* has created instad of *href=/static/media/data_report.f1b9ba61.json* or something, resulting url http://localhost:3000/[object%20object] . FYI, I'm using same manner to display other files like `yaml, xml` etc which are working fine. Can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you `console.log(metadata)` ?

Comment: You don't need `require` there.

Comment: @RedBaron here is one of metadata array, 

`Name: "P2IRC Template"`
`mimetype: "application/json"`
`url: "/Root Imaging Research Group_42/JsonDataForSchemLoad.json" `